# How to get selected row in DataGrid in smartphone application?

Tags: .net, datagrid, compact-framework, smartphone

I am working on a smartphone application, where I have a DataGrid in winform.

I want to get the value of cell of the selected row..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will return the value of selected cell of DataGrid in smartphone application

```
   MessageBox.Show(dgDataGrid[dgDataGrid.CurrentCell.RowNumber,
 dgDataGrid.CurrentCell.ColumnNumber].ToString());
```

Through this you can get or set the cell value.

Comment: Your answer is the same as `dgDataGrid.Item(i, 0)` as shown in @Zordey's answer. This is because VB.NET allows the user to call the `Item` method directy. This method is an "indexer" property. In C# this method is "hidden" and accessed as `this[index]`. In VB.NET, you can access as `Me(index)` or `Me.Item(index)`.

Answer (score 4):

Through lack of information here is a hack of one if our methods from an old VB.net compact framework project.

```
For i As Integer = 1 To DataGrid.VisibleRowCount - 1

  If DataGrid.IsSelected(i) Then

    MessageBox.Show(DataGrid.Item(i, 0).ToString())

  End If

Next
```

This will show a message box with the contents of the first cell of each selected row.

Comment: thanks for answer but there no function like DataGrid.Item(i, 0) in DataGrid ... please verify it

Comment: Hi, as I said this is an old project for a Win CE5 PDA device using compact framework 2.0.
I dont actually have a later version currently installed to test.

you could try something like:
     DataGrid.row(i)(0).tostring()

Sorry for not being more help.

Comment: Sorry but there is no row function in DataGrid in smartphone application. I got it. thanks for reply...

Comment: @Azhar: Your answer is the same as `dgDataGrid.Item(i, 0)` as shown in @Zordey's answer. This is because VB.NET allows the user to call the `Item` method directy. This method is an "indexer" property. In C# this method is "hidden" and accessed as `this[index]`. In VB.NET, you can access as `Me(index)` or `Me.Item(index)`.